# Making elements of a matrix multiples of 42 without changing sum of any row or column

Tags: math, matrix

I stumbled across this interesting question: https://prologin.org/train/2016/semifinal/42_le_retour (in French).

In short, we're given a matrix composed of random numbers, i.e.:

```
40 0 2
0 84 0
2 42 40
```

The objective is to modify the elements in this matrix so that they are all divisible by `42`; however, the sum of any row and column should remain the same as before any modification. (The original problem was to calculate the minimum *clicks* needed, supposing each click adds or subtracts 1)

I am wondering whether and why this is always possible.

Comment: What kind of modifications are we talking about? Adding and subtracting 1 from each element or are the operations on rows/columns?

Comment: Adding and subtracting 1 without changing sums of any row / column.

Answer (score 1):

Possible moves in a 3x3 matrix are:

1. - adding +-1 to a corner value
   - adding +-1 to the opposing corner
   - adding -+1 to the neighboring corner

2.

- adding +-1 to a corner value
- adding -+1 to the neighbor values
- adding +-1 to the middle value

The first possibility has two variants, differing only in sign. The second possibility has a total of 8 variants (four different corners and different sizes).

I do not know whether this is always possible, especially since we do not know the limits of the matrix and it is unclear whether we have a square matrix at all. However, you can check this using backtracking. Whenever you reach a matrix where each element modulo 42 are the same as initially, you need to trace back, until you find a solution.

Comment: Yes we're sure it is a square matrix; however if we have a 4*4 one, the _middle value_ becomes the _middle values_?

Comment: @JingjieYANG not really. In that case the number of possible steps increases significantly. You can change corners, or corner and neighbors, or corner and non-corner non-neighbors in the same row and column along with the furthest middle element, or non corner edges and middle elements near them, or non-corners and middle elements not near them, or opposing non-corners, or the four middle elements.